# Closed form solution for $a_n = 1,11,111,1111,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying find a closed form for the sequence

$$\begin{matrix}
a_1&1\\
a_2&11\\
a_3&111\\
\cdots&\cdots\\
a_9&111111111\\
a_{10}&12222222121\\
\cdots&\cdots
\end{matrix}$$

In other words:

For:

$$b_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_n$$

where $$b_n = \{1,12,123,1234,...,12345678910,1234567891011,...\}$$

Is there a closed form solution for $a_n$?

I am completely stuck; Is this not possible?

Comment: Won't that mean $a_{10}=12345678910-123456789=12222222121$?

Comment: If you find anything to improve http://oeis.org/A078998 or http://oeis.org/A007908, please submit there

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thank you for noticing!

Answer (score 2):

We have $b_n=10 b_{n-1} \cdot 10^{\lfloor \log_{10}(n)\rfloor}+n$ and $a_n = b_n - b_{n-1}$.